# Functions do not appear/run on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I can successfully deploy the HelloWord application fine as per the video guide [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ).

But now I was following the instructions [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/3rd-party-service/firebase-algolia/) in order to link Algolia and Firebase with Cloud Functions, I can run the code on my computer and it updates, but somehow it does not auto-update when I make changes on Firebase.

Secondly, when I deploy the application I get the "deploy complete" message but nothing appears in Firebase>>Functions and Algolia is not updated when I make changes to Firebase.

index.js code

```js
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const firebase = require('firebase');

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();

// configure firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
});
const database = firebase.database();

// configure algolia
const algolia = algoliasearch(
  process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
  process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY
);
const index = algolia.initIndex(process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);

//synchronize firebase database with algolia index
const contactsRef = database.ref('/contactDetail/botswana');
contactsRef.on('child_added', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);
contactsRef.on('child_changed', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);
contactsRef.on('child_removed', deleteIndexRecord);

function addOrUpdateIndexRecord(contact) {
  // Get Firebase object
  const record = contact.val();
  // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
  record.objectID = contact.key;
  // Add or update object
  index
    .saveObject(record)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Firebase object indexed in Algolia', record.objectID);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error when indexing contact into Algolia', error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
}

function deleteIndexRecord(contact) {
  // Get Algolia's objectID from the Firebase object key
  const objectID = contact.key;
  // Remove the object from Algolia
  index
    .deleteObject(objectID)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Firebase object deleted from Algolia', objectID);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error when deleting contact from Algolia', error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
}
```

package.json code

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "algoliasearch": "^3.24.9",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "firebase": "^4.8.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make few changes to the code before it runs

1. functions needed to be exported using "exports"
2. functions does not use .on() as listener instead use e.g. onCreate() with one parameter, more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#monitoring_changed_values). See below

   `exports.childAdded=contactsRef.onCreate(addOrUpdateIndexRecord);`

Solution:

```js
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();

// configure algolia
const algolia = algoliasearch(
  process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
  process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY
);
const index = algolia.initIndex(process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);

//synchronize firebase database with algolia index
const contactsRef = functions.database.ref('/contactDetail/locationA/{contactID}');

exports.childAdded=contactsRef.onCreate(addOrUpdateIndexRecord);
exports.childChanged=contactsRef.onUpdate(addOrUpdateIndexRecord); 
exports.childRemoved=contactsRef.onDelete(deleteIndexRecord);

function addOrUpdateIndexRecord(contact) {
  console.log("The function addOrUpdateIndexRecord is running!");
  // Get Firebase object
  const record = contact.data.val(); 
  
  // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
  record.objectID = contact.data.key;
  // Add or update object
  return index 
    .saveObject(record)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Firebase object indexed in Algolia', record.objectID);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error when indexing contact into Algolia', error);
      process.exit(1);
    });      
}

function deleteIndexRecord(contact) {
  // Get Algolia's objectID from the Firebase object key
  const objectID = contact.data.key; 
  // Remove the object from Algolia
  return index
    .deleteObject(objectID)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Firebase object deleted from Algolia', objectID);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error when deleting contact from Algolia', error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the logs in the `Functions` section ? In order to see changes in Algolia, you should first see the function appearing in your firebase console.

Comment: there is nothing in the logs, the function doesnt even appear on Functions

Comment: First, try removing most of the code to see if the function is getting deployed correctly. Check too if you declared your environment variables correctly like: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL, ALGOLIA_APP_ID, etc